# Many objects under objects

Tags: php, mysql

I have a doubt about relationship and how to show it.

I have a channel which can have many channels, which can have more channels, which can have more channels..........

How can I relate them?

I thought that each channel can have a field that tells which channel it's related to, like:

```
id name related_channel
2  example1 null
3  example2 2
4  example3 2
5  example4 4
```

what do you think about it?

After relating them, how can show all the channels that are under a channel?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a big fan of the self-joins, especially with stored procs to do near recursive (but not) operations on them. I wrote up an example in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31967073/1816093). Let any of us know if you need any help like that. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Drew! That's exactly what I needed!

Comment: self-joins are awesome for re-hanging a whole sub-hierarchy, eh ? Glad you found some use of the link.

Answer (score 1):

this approach is good, you just need to set a "parent_id" or "related_channel" in your case.

after that, if you want to get all childrens of a channel, just use SQL Query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM channel where related_channel=x
```

Comment: NIce! Thanks man. The only problem in this query is that if I have this situation:
channel1 > channel2 > channel3
When I use this query:
SELECT * FROM channel where related_channel = 1
the channel3 wouldn't appear, because his related_channel is 2, but he is also child of channel1